# What is the best time to drink a cup of coffee?

Tags: health

Coffee is good for health but everything is good on time,i drink coffee every morning but i want to know that is it the right time to drink coffee or any other time is suitable for a cup of coffee?so it will not have a bad effect on my health.

Answer (score 2):

Right Time = Any time. Unless caffeine is something that keeps you up at night. In that case, in the morning after you wake up is a good time to have a cup or 3.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the morning after I arrive at work.  Found this interesting article:
https://nationalpost.com/life/food/when-are-the-best-times-in-the-day-to-drink-coffee

Comment: Hi @MarkB, could you please share a summary of the contents of the article as it may disappear from the internet in the future or it may not be immediately accessible for some of our audience.